# for...of loops, array destructuring and Array.prototype.entries() - should they work together?

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native

So I have a react-native app. For what it's worth we are using redux & redux-saga for state/action management. I've recently found that certain android devices are crashing in one of our sagas, the code for which looks like this (typescript):

```
function* displayTemplates(templateEffectProviders: EffectProvider[]) {
  for (const [i, templateEffectProvider] of templateEffectProviders.entries()) {
    // ...loop code
  }
}
```

I can guarantee that the function is only ever called with an array (other than typescript compiler suggesting this, the function is only ever called with an array literal as the only argument, such as `yield call(displayTemplates, [getTemplate1EffectProvider(), getTemplate2EffectProvider()]);`)

Most devices handle this fine, however some android devices (so far as I can see: Samsung Galaxy or Note devices on Android 7) crash at the opening of the for...of loop, with the error:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating 't["function"==typeof Symbol&&"function"==typeof Symbol?Symbol.iterator:"@@iterator"]()')
```

Clearly this error refers to the transpiled code, which boils down to the following (after I clean it up a bit):

```
t = e.entries(),
n = Array.isArray(t),
o = 0,
t = n ? t : t["function"==typeof Symbol&&"function"==typeof Symbol?Symbol.iterator:"@@iterator"]()
```

(Yes, that `"function"==typeof Symbol` check is doubled up, no I have no idea why... No idea if that is related)

Our .babelrc looks like:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"
  ],
  "sourceMaps": "inline",
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-jsx-source"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It feels to me like maybe the js engine in those devices does not handle the output of that babel transpilation for some reason, but I am having difficulties figuring out why. I know, for instance, that the `react-navigation` package saw the [same error message](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2853) when destructuring a string, which was fixed [by removing the destructuring](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/commit/ed2fc9a09e2f562ae9d3fc7f5df17c593989db0a). I know I can replace my for...of loop with an incremented for loop, but I am just trying to figure out why this is a problem so that I can have some confidence in applying that as a fix.

Edit: My continued reading and investigation on this would suggest that this might due to a lack of a Symbol polyfill in React Native, and it not being supported natively in Android JavaScriptCore. I'm not 100% confident on this, and would still gladly accept an answer that definitively answers the question.